# Running terminal command on all files in folder?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

I need to convert 500+ .xlsx files to .txt (or .csv). To do this I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256733/convert-xlsx-file-to-csv-using-batch). It works well if I write the command like this:

```
xlsx2csv fileA.xlsx fileA.txt
```

I have however been unable to run the command on all files (500+ files) in the current folder. Could you please help me with that?

---

I Know I had figured out how to do this some time ago (via google) and I have tried again today but I did not have any luck for the last hour. So please forgive me asking such a likely simple question. 
Thanks for your Help.

Comment: See the linked question. You need to change the output file name in a loop. `for f in *.xslx; do xlsx2csv "$f" "${f%.xslx}.txt"; done`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why you have put ...{f%.xslx}... here and had it as ...{f%%... in your answer for the other question?

Comment: Ah, there is virtually no difference. `%%` deletes the longest match of the string `.xslx`, while `%` deletes the shortest match (always from the back of the string though). Since there are no matching patterns here, but just literal strings, it does not matter. Just one character less. See also http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html